# OpenGL/glut background polygons appear to overlap foreground plygons

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I am new to OpenGL, and I am having trouble displaying a simple cube on my screen. The problem is that sides of the cube that should be hidden in the background still appear. I feel that the answer should be that I have to enable GL_DEPTH_TEST, but this causes the screen to display a complete white canvas with nothing on it. Here's a sample from a run I have done:

[image: example]

Each side is just a random color.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowSize(600, 400);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_DEPTH);


glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(50.0, 1.5, 1.0f, 100.0);
gluLookAt(10.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
//glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  /* white */
```

I have commented out glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) for now.

What else should I be doing so that there is no overlapping on this cube?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, and clear the depth buffer before rendering with `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`.
This can be combined with `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` if you're using that, as `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what needed to be added. Everything works as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @immibis said about depth buffers, you can also turn on back-face culling and make sure that you draw your primitives facing the correct direction. To do that:

```
glEnable (GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace (GL_BACK);
glFrontFace (GL_CW); // This says you define your primitives in clockwise order
```

That causes faces that are pointing away from the camera not to be drawn which can improve performance, and can eliminate this particular problem as well. (But you probably want to use a depth buffer, too.)